# How do I remove the fglrx driver error?

Tags: ati, fglrx, error-handling

Every time I log in to my computer system error message is shown. It is something to do with fglrx driver for ati graphics card that its installation couldn't be completed. I am really annoyed with that driver and have no intention on fixing it as long as my computer runs smoothly. Is there a way to "don't show this again I am irresponsible and really don't care"?

Comment: Have you tried opening synaptic and uninstalling the fglrx driver?

Comment: i tried but it seems like it is partially installed because then i can't even log to gnome so that's not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rPress <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> and log in.

Now type:

```
sudo dpkg -l '*fglrx*'
```

If that doesn't work you might try reconfiguring everything:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

If that doesn't work then try removing the drivers with

```
sudo dpkg -r '*fglrx*'
```